# Securing a web service, asp.net mvc 3, encryption

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-3, encryption

I'm creating a web service (asmx) using asp.net mvc 3 and it has a few web methods that send and receive data. I want to encrypt this data as it goes in and out. Does anyone know of any references that might help me out? Or have a solution? I'm quite new to this, although I've done some reading I haven't found anything on the best way to protect information going in and out of the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest thing to do is to make your web service endpoints secure using SSL certificate.

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649205.aspx) for more info

Also, I would recommend using WCF as it will give you more configuration options (a lot more!)   but is also widely used. See this [article for more info](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCF.aspx) about using SSL with WCF

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So if I used SSL certificate this would encrypt the data that I send out from the server? I wouldn't have to create an encryption class or something and have synchronized keys if I used the certificate?

Comment: that's right - the data would be encrypted at the transport layer (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)

Comment: if you are storing sensitive information in a database then I recommend encrypting that data (see this question for hints on that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-net)